# Should I move the code from code behind file to ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm

I have buttons and slider in the window. Also I have a button click event. The thing is I use the click event in code behind. However I also adopt MVVW pattern. So I guess that I may convert the code with `ICommand` etc. I am not sure if it is a right decision.

**Please look at my code and advise me.** I am new to `ICommand` and `CanExecute`.

```
MainViewModel _dataContext;
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _dataContext = new MainViewModel();
    this.DataContext = _dataContext;
    _dataContext.ServerString = "  Connected to Server " +  ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Server"]";
}

private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        cTokenSource = new buttonCancellationTokenSource();
        cToken = cTokenSource.Token;
        paymentTestNumber = count;
        buttonStart.IsEnabled = false;
        buttonStart.IsHitTestVisible = false;
        buttonStart.Background = Brushes.Red;
        buttonCancel.IsEnabled = true;
        buttonCancel.Background = Brushes.Green;
        buttonCancel.IsHitTestVisible = true;

        _dataContext.Items.Clear();
        _dataContext.PaymentTotal = PaymentTotal;
        _dataContext.TotalSuccess = string.Empty;
        _dataContext.TotalFail = string.Empty;
        m_Queue = new BufferBlock<AppointmentReminder>(new DataflowBlockOptions { BoundedCapacity = 1000 }); // bufferBlock
        slider.IsEnabled = false;
        var producer = Producer(paymentTestNumber);
        var consumer = Consumer();

        await Task.WhenAll(producer, consumer);
        Summary();
        slider.IsEnabled = true;
        cTokenSource = null;
    }
```

For the **View Model**.

```
public class MainViewModel : NotifyUIBase
{
    private string serverString;
    public string ServerString
    {
        get { return serverString; }
        set
        {
            serverString = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Calls> items = new ObservableCollection<Calls>();
    public ObservableCollection<Calls> Items
    {
        get { return items; }
        set
        {
            items = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

It works well but it may be against the MVVM priciple.
So my question is: Do I need convert the event `buttonStart_Click` to `ICommand` etc.?

Comment: That's not a VM, that's a Model.  Business logic goes in the VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you're also manipulating data, not just visuals, so it definitely belongs to ViewModel.

To further address your question from the comment, you don't access controls directly, but rather you set boolean variables in ViewModel and use that instead. Also for setting colors you might use setters or even custom controls, depends on exact needs. There are multiple ways of doing it.

Comment: If I do it, how can I access the control in ViewModel? Such as `buttonStart.IsEnabled = false;` and `buttonStart.Background = Brushes.Red;`

Comment: Thank you. A piece of code would be appreciated. I mean for boolen variables.

Comment: They're just simple bool variables. You can bind properties of controls to them directly, or sometimes better, use bool for determining if the command can be executed. If not, it will disable the button by default. Depends on implementation of ICommand you're using, but it usually accepts two parameters. One is a action and seconds is a bool.

Comment: you should never be accessing the control in the ViewModel - and I would only turn part of your code behind into commands.  The visual manipulation (setting properties on the button) should remain in the codebehind.  The datacontext manipulation can go into the viewmodel.

Comment: @Andrew, I may agree with you. Convert partial instead of the whole may be a right solution. The hard part is some visual changes in button click event. If I use ICommand, I have to access the controls from ViewModel.

Comment: @HuiZhao, no, you never access controls directly, you just use binding ;) That's the whole point.

Answer (score 0):

If you are manipulating data (something with no inherent visual representation), then go ahead an turn the button-clicks into commands and put them in your viewmodel.  That way, the logic that acts on data lives with the data in the VM.  If you are manipulating visual state of your control, do it in the code behind.

It's perfectly fine for your control to reference your VM through the DataContext property of the view. It is NOT OK for your ViewModel to have a reference to your View. If that is done, you've coupled the visual representation of your data to the data itself, and the whole point of MVVM is to avoid that.

Furthermore, if you find yourself writing VM properties such as ButtonEnabled or HighlightColor (things that are meant to be in the view layer), something is wrong.

Comment: Can I directly move my methods say `Producer` and `Consumer` to `MainViewModel`?

Comment: depends - what do they do?